# Can I see detailed browser history on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari, mobile-safari, history, browser-history

I have an iPhone 4 on iOS 5.1. When I go into Safari's History page, I can see my browsing history by day, but I need to know what page I visited two days ago, at a specific time. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mobile safari does not have that feature and the application sandbox means you likely won't get at that data from another app running on the device without jailbreaking.

Many tools can export the browsing history to your computer - the trial version of [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview.html) might be good to start and see if that meets your needs.

History files in particular are stored as .webloc files.

Comment: Oh, I see -- so it doesn't even store that data, it just stores them as bookmarks in a History folder. Oh, well...

Thanks anyway!

Comment: There is a history database that stores page thumbnails and an index to content on the desktop safari, but mobile safari is thinner. Hopefully, it time stamps the bookmarks in the file system so you could still search by date order.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the time as in which hour and minute? As far as I know, there's no way to do this. I don't think this is possible in Safari desktop either.

Comment: In Safari Mac this is possible.

Comment: >this is possible

then why not explain how to do it @NicolasBarbulesco... anyone reading this...don't give useless answers without explanation...it's highly offputting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

1. Make a backup of your iPhone to iTunes.
2. Explore the backup. To do so, iExplorer is nice. If necessary, export the file *History.plist* and view it with TextWrangler.